# Loading html page via redirect for image load from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scenario where I am loading an image from javascript via:
Something like:

```
<script type ="javascript" >
var img1=new Image(1,1);
img1.src='img2.jpg';
</script>
```

Now the requirement is to redirect the call to the image to an html page which will further load 3-4 images(for tracking purpose)basically.
But I am getting warning in chrome and load able to load images from the html page.

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html:

Please let me know if there is a workaround for this issue.

Requirement: 
We are sending call to fetch image to server via javascript but we want to load html page which has bunch of images to be loaded

Comment: The warning means that image is being sent with MIM type 'text/html'. Check whether correct MIME type is set at server

Comment: thats the requirement.We are sending call to fetch image to server via javascript but we want to load html page which has bunch of images to be loaded

Comment: Then you cannot set the URL of the HTML page to Image.src. You should send a seperate AJAX call.

Comment: You can't point an image to a HTML page, you'll need a different solution. What have you tried?

Comment: I redirected the image to html page using 302 but thats not working

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correct what you have done then the `src` attribute of the `img` tag expects a response of type image e.g. `image/jpg`. You give a page so the response is of type `text/html`.